# CORS fetch for different ports

Tags: javascript, cookies, cors, fetch

I need to send fetch request(using java script), and when I sending it from localhost:8080 it's fine, but when I'm changing localhost to other - there is 303 response or no response at all.

Also it's including cookies when I sending it from 8080, and NOT sending from other host.

Where could be problem? I'm totally lost.

Comment: How would we know what the problem is without seeing your code?

Answer (score 4):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) has some quite good documentation on CORS and `fetch`.

When you call fetch on a different origin with a CORS flag:

```
fetch(url, {method: 'GET', mode: 'cors'})
```

if the url is from a different origin, `fetch` will first issue an `OPTION` request with headers:

```
Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
```

The server must confirm that origin is allowed for such requests, sending response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

Most likely your server does not have CORS enabled. This can be easily checked via browser console network requests. Check that `OPTIONS` is sent and replied to by the server, also that your site is present in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header communicated back.

Please note, if your server requires authorization, you should call `fetch` with `{credentials: 'include'}`:

```
fetch(url, {method: 'GET', mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include'})
```

Comment: "Most likely server side does not have CORS enabled" — That wouldn't explain the results the OP is describing.

Comment: Why not, it depends on server implementation. "does not have CORS enabled" means CORS not enabled for the origin he is sending from.

Comment: I would expect "Method Not Allowed" or a normal response (which is inaccessible to JS) if CORS wasn't set up. I wouldn't expect no response at all or a 303 redirect.

Comment: Redirect on CORS preflight is allowed by standard, though not supported by most browsers: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/commit/0d9a4db8bc02251cc9e391543bb3c1322fb882f2

Comment: Anyways, the issue is on server side.

Comment: Probably, but since the question doesn't include any server or client side code, we can't determine how to fix it.